# Is the trace map open for $p$-adic field?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and $L$ be a finite extension of $K$, then is the trace map $O_L\rightarrow O_K$ open? I guess this should be true, but I don't know how to prove.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p\nmid [L:K]$ then $$Tr_{L/K}(\pi_K^n O_L) = \pi_K^nO_K$$
Do you think the case $p\ |\ [K:\Bbb{Q}_p]$ changes something ? (try with $K=\Bbb{Q}_2(2^{1/2})$)

Comment: What is your guess

Comment: What is the trace of elements of $O_K$..